# LEFT JOIN only first match

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Please help me write a subquery for a join.

**table pages**

```
P1
P2
P3
P4
```

**actions**

```
A1: page_id = P1, type = 'view', date = '2015-02-10 12:23:00'
A2: page_id = P1, type = 'view', date = '2015-02-11 13:12:23'
A3: page_id = P3, type = 'view', date = '2015-02-12 09:33:23'
A4: page_id = P4, type = 'click', date = '2015-02-12 10:12:12'
A5: page_id = P5, type = 'view', date = '2015-02-12 15:47:32'
```

I need to count pages views by days (we don't need to count other views of page, only first open):

```
'2015-02-10': 1
'2015-02-12': 2
```

**Template of SQL**

```
SELECT DATE(date) AS period, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM pages p
LEFT JOIN actions a ON a.page_id = p.id { ??? }
WHERE a.type = 'view'
GROUP BY period
```

**Updated**

I've tried to write this SQL, but it executes a long time (~ 2 sec)

```
SELECT DATE(a.date) AS period, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM pages p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(date) as date, page_id
    FROM actions
    WHERE type = 'view'
    GROUP BY page_id
) a ON a.page_id = p.id
WHERE a.type = 'view'
GROUP BY period
```

Comment: Are you trying to find what needs to be placed in this part ==> { ??? } of the query ?

Comment: Create sub-query with `LIMIT 1` and use it for `JOIN`.

Comment: @vijayalakshmid yes, I hope you'll help me to write whole left join statement correctly

Comment: Why do you use DATE() function? What is the data type of date field?

Comment: @Ragnar date is datetime field, so I need to group results by dates

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. I don't think you've explained very well what you're trying to accomplish. Also, it appears you have a working solution, so are you looking for a way to make it faster?